# Can anyone explain the working of jsonld.compact() ? Wasn't able to find detailed documentation or examples for the compact() method

Tags: python-3.x, json-ld

```
def process_all_imdb(cursor, imdb):
    for i, mid in enumerate(get_movies_to_process(cursor)):
        print "// %d movies processed." % i
        movie = get_jsonld_from_imdb(imdb, mid)

        movie = jsonld.compact(movie, 'http://schema.org/')
        print json.dumps(movie, indent=4)
```

Couldn't understand how jsonld.compact() here was working.

**Ref:**
https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/pyld.jsonld/-/compact/python-compact-function-examples.html#0xa049c4d89ef404c3d9e4b4b59fbea78ee06e58b66f366ec8eb81ea8b7ebf712d-283,,289,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general form of Compacted JSON-LD is described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#compacted-document-form), with several examples.

The operation of the algorithm, is described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-api/#compaction-algorithms), although details of [Context Processing](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-api/#context-processing-algorithms) are pertinent.

There is a complete [test-suite](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-api/tests/compact-manifest.html) contains many examples of compacting expanded JSON-LD documents.

All implementations of JSON-LD 1.1 conform to these algorithms. The document you referenced uses [pyld](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/pyld), which is highly conformant.